# Adding new rows in pandas dataframe at specific index

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have read all the answers related to my question available in stackoverflow but my question is little different from available answers. I have very large dataframe and some portion of that dataframe is following-

```
Input Dataframe is like
    A          B                                                                       C       D
0  foot     17/1: OGChan_2020011717711829281829281  , 7days                           ...      
1  arm     this will processed after                                                  ;;;
2  leg     go_2020011625692400374400374 16/1: Id Imerys_2020011618188744093744093    
3  head    xyziemen_2020011510691787006787006 en_2020011510749462801462801            ;;;                                                     
:   :             :                                                                    :
```

In this dataframe, firstly I am extracting ID's from column B based upon some regular expression. Some rows of Column B may contain that ID's, some may not and some rows of column B may blank. Following is the code-

```
df = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx", "Sheet1")
dict= {}
for i in df.index:
    j = str(df['B'][i])
    if(re.findall('_\d{25}', j)):
        a = re.findall('_\d{25}', j)
        print(a)
        dict[i] = a
```

Regular Expression starts with _(undersore) and 25 digits. Example in above df are _2020011618188744093744093, _2020011510749462801462801 etc..

Now I want to insert these ID's in Column D of a particular row. For Example If two ID's are find at 0th row than first ID should insert in 0th row of column D and second Id should insert on 1st row of column D and all the content of dataframe should shifted down. What I want will clear from following output.I want my output as following based upon above input.

```
     A                B                                      ..                  D                                                         
0    foot     17/1: OGChan_2020011717711829281829281 ,7days     _2020011717711829281829281
1    arm      this will processed after                            
2    leg      go_2020011625692400374400374 16/1:                _2020011625692400374400374
              Id Imerys_2020011618188744093744093
3                                                               _2020011618188744093744093
4    head     xyziemen_2020011510691787006787006                _2020011510691787006787006
              en_2020011510749462801462801
5                                                               _2020011510749462801462801
:     :          :                                                    :
```

In above output 1 ID is found at 0th row.So column D of 0th row contains that ID. No ID is found at first index. So column D of 1st index is empty. At second index there are two ID's. Hence first ID is placed on 2nd row of column D and second ID is placed on 3rd row of column D and it shifted the previous content of third row to 4th row. I want above output as my final output.

Hope I am clear. Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't understand how you split the content of column B into two lines. But you can get closer to your output by `df.assign(D=df["B"].str.findall(r"(_[0-9]{25})")).explode("D")`.

Comment: @HenryYik Thank you for your response. I have not split content of column B in two line.It is in one line only. It is typing mistake and hence appears in two lines for some rows. But I want my final output as explained by me in column D. Can you please help me to solve this task

Comment: @HenryYik Thank you very much. Your solution works for me. Your solution is my answer